# getting a file location from IE9 drag or drop event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Is it at all possible to get the filename location from a *drag* or *drop* event in IE9 ?

i've tried:

```
    $('#myDiv').addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (e.dataTransfer.files === undefined) // <-- true
```

or

```
    $('#dropTarget').on('drop', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer){
            if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) // <-- files is undefined..
```

are there **any other tricks** that could be done to get that location on a drag/drop in IE9?

Comment: Even if IE9 supported the HTML5 File API (it doesn't) you could never get the file "location" information, only the leaf filename. Browsers work hard to protect user privacy by not leaking file path information; that's why uploaded files are assigned the dummy path "C:\fakepath\actualfilename" for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE 9 does not support the File API
Here is a compatibility chart

http://caniuse.com/#search=fileapi

Comment: is there anything that can be done in ie9 to capture this information?

Comment: no not with your drag and drop operation - You would have to through the regular user initiated "browse for the file" operation.